# Does Judaism appreciate the wanton destruction of idolatry done by Islamic groups?

Tags: gentiles, avodah-zarah, current-events

Many of the idolatrous heritage sites like Bamiyan Buddha, Sufi shrines, and Hindu idols are being destroyed by Islamic fundamentalists around the globe. Does Judaism allow a non Jew to demolish such idolatry or is it encouraged for a Jew to recommend and help a gentile in eradicating idolatry by any means possible?

Comment: I don't know that the Buddhas of Bamiyan were idols.

Comment: Very related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28969/does-demolishing-idolatry-require-specific-authority

Comment: Sufi is not idolatry AFAIK.

Comment: I suppose Judaism would also appreciate Unitarianism (a Christian sect which says G-d is one and reject the Trinity).

Answer (score 2):

Technically, yes. It is a mitzvah to destroy Idolatrous artifacts and currently existing Idols

Comment: The Christians also destroy idols, just not their own.

Comment: Yes, but does that extend to non-Jews (i.e. Noachides)? Does that extend to places that are not under Jewish rule? As I see it, that's what the question is about. (The mitzvah you mention is implicitly acknowledged in the question, otherwise the question would be meaningless.)