# Brachos on mitzvos no longer practiced

Tags: blessing, mitzvah, korban, tractate-brachot

I am currently working on a project devising a list of all Brachot ever made in the history of yiddishkeit. So far I have 198, based on prevalent practice today as well as various poskim and, gemara, tosefta etc.

I have hit a brick wall with Brachot over mitzvot - it is difficult to find sources which discuss what Brachot were made during zman bait sheni (after the takana of Brachot by the anshei knesset hagedolah) that are no longer talui bazman hazeh.

Namely, does anybody know of Brachot that were made on various temple services, from menorah to korbanot to parah aduma etc?

Anybody who knows of sources and/nuschayot please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Get the sefer ברכות המצוות כתיקונן by מנחם שוימר. He discusses all of this.

Comment: Destroying idols applies nowadays too https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28971/759

Comment: This isn't really one question...

Comment: Re Menorah - see Raavad, Hil. Brachos 11:15: אי נמי מפני שזו הברכה הוקבעה על נרות שבמקדש שהם של תורה...

Comment: Re: bikkurim, see Derech Emunah, Bikkurim 2:19

Comment: Re: Throwing neveila to dogs, this is not a mitzvah

Comment: See also https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%96_%D7%A0

Comment: You cant really make a brachah on "Shikcha" since its a mitzvah that is done passively by forgetting and after you forgot the bundles the mitzva is done.

Comment: Ramban in hasagos to Sefer Hamitzvos Shoresh 12 writes that every part of the עבודה required a blessing, including בלילות יציקות וכו׳. See Mishneh Lemelech (מעשה הקרבנות א:א) who cites conflicting opinions as to the Rambam's opinion on this.

Comment: Shichrur Avadim?

Comment: Concerning shichrur avadim - by and large don’t we refrain from Brachot on mitzvot bein Adam lechavero?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding eating *korban bechor* or *maaser*, it would seem that there one does make a blessing:

The Tosefta (Berachos 5:22) codifies a blessing for the sacrificing and eating of Korbanos.

> היה מקריב זבחים בירושלים אומר ברוך שהגיענו לזמן הזה כשהוא מקריבם אומר
> בא"י אקב"ו להקריב זבחים כשהוא אוכלם אומר בא"י אקב"ו **לאכול זבחים**.

Whether the Tosefta is discussing the Kohen or the owner is a debate amongst the Rishonim in Menachos 75b (see *Rashi, Rashi ksav had, Tosfos*).

Rashi (Zevachim 32a) quotes a Tosefta (Pesachim 10:8 - see original for different wording) with a slightly different variation of this blessing (referring to Chaggiga):

> ועל הזבח הוא אומר אשר קדשנו במצותיו וצונו **לאכול את הזבח**

Rashi in Pesachim (121b) cites this blessing with yet a third variation:

> על של זבח חגיגת ארבעה עשר ומברכין **על** **אכילת שלמים**

(See *Mishneh L'melech* Hil. Maaseh Karbanos 10:1 regarding *asham* and *chatas* specifically; he adds to say אשר קדשנו **בקדושתו של אהרן** וצונו לאכול חטאת/אשם, based on Rambam Terumos 15:23, however this would only be by sacrifices that are exclusively eaten by Kohanim)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding 3 from the list - *Mitat beit din*, *Malkut* and *sotah* procedure:

In a famous teshuva that provides many rules of *Birchas Hamitzvos*, R Yosef ibn Plat (quoted partially in Teshuvos haRashba 18, and more extensively in Avudraham [Sha'ar 3 Birchas Hamitzvos](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Abudarham%2C_Third_Gate%3B_Blessings_on_Commandments)) rules that one doesn't bless on destruction - therefore precluding the 4 Capital Punishments, *malkus*, and the *sotah* procedure from *Birchas hamitzvos*.

> וכן לא מברכינן על ארבע מיתות בית דין ולא על מלקות דקודשא בריך הוא חס
> על בריותיו כדדרשי' בכי קללת אלוקים תלוי. א"ר מאיר מאי הלשון הזה אומרת
> קלני מראשי וכו' וכדדרשי' בלא קרב זה אל זה וכו' וכדאמרי' שאין אומר הלל
> בראש השנה מפני שהוא שעת הדין. וכדאמרינן נמי אין מפסיקין בקללות מפני
> שאין אומרים ברכה על הפורענות. והוא הדין שאין מברכין על השקאת סוטה.

I wonder if that could be extended to another 2 from the list: *Burial of executed* and *Hanging corpse of somebody that was stoned*?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding *bracha* on *eglah arufah* and *zerikah*, R' Yosef Ibn Plat (in [responsa](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Abudarham%2C_Third_Gate%3B_Blessings_on_Commandments) cited [above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/131872/17563)) rules that they do indeed require a *brachah*.

> אבל על **עריפת עגלה מברכין** וכן על הקרבת הקרבנות ועל סמיכה **וזריקה**
> והקטר אימורין ושאר מעשיהן והוא הדין ליציקת שמן על תנוך אזן מצורע ועל
> בהן ידו ומאי דדאמי להו וכל מעשה מנחות דהוו מברכין עליהו.

Comment: Ramban in hasagos to Sefer Hamitzvos Shoresh 12 writes that every part of the עבודה required a blessing, including בלילות יציקות וכו׳. See Mishneh Lemelech (מעשה הקרבנות א:א) who cites conflicting opinions whether Rambam agrees, or only requires blessing for 'עבודה גדולה', which Mishneh Lemelech points out is difficult to define.